# How to add/use <QtMath> with Qt 5.0.2

Tags: c++, qt, math, qtcore, qt5.1

I have been trying to add `<QtMath`> to my Qt so I can use `qDegreesToRadians` and such but when I add `#include <QtMath>` it says no such file or directory.

Here's Qt's website about QtMath:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qtmath.html#details

How do I QtMath, or what have I done wrong?

Comment: That function was added in Qt 5.1 and is not available in Qt 5.0.2. You'll want to upgrade your version of Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added these functions in 5.1, so you cannot use them in 5.0.2. See the documentation note about in each corresponding section:

> This function was introduced in QtCore 5.1.

Here is the corresponding Gerrit change:

[Add qDegreesToRadians and qRadiansToDegrees math functions](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,45851)

But `#include <QtMath>` or `#include <QtCore/QtMath>` should just work (once you update, for sure) because there are these lines in the source that I added:

```
#if 0
#pragma qt_class(QtMath)
#endif
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I am still having the same problems, I have updated to Qt 5.2. I am on KuBuntu and I do not understand why it didn't work. My friend has the same OS and his QtMath works (though he has 5.1)

Any other ideas?

Comment: @user3498383: what do you mean "it did not work"? Would it be possible to show the error and the corresponding code?

Comment: It still says it has no such file or directory